# Button Activities to another page

Tags: android, button

on the MainActivity I have several Buttons and I want that each button is going to another xml page. I have the code for one Button to one page that's working. But I can't get the solution the code to solved this problem.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceStae){
    super.onCreate(savedInstancesState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_index);

    Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v){

    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), voorbeeld.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
  });
 }

//This is only for one button, has somebody a solution to work with several buttons
```

Answer (score 3):

implement your activity with onclicklistner and write the code like bellow

```
public class MainActiv1ity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
       Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
       Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
       Button button4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
       button1.setOnClickListener(this);
       button2.setOnClickListener(this);
       button3.setOnClickListener(this);
       button4.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
        //do your logic
        break;
    case R.id.button2:
        //do your logic
        break;
    case R.id.button3:
        //do your logic
        break;
    case R.id.button4:
        //do your logic
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

In the XML for each button, add a new `android:onClick="methodName"`, with a different methodName for each button.

Then in your activity class, add methods with that name that take a view as a parameter and create a new intent for each one:

```
public void methodName2(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), activityForButton1.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
public void methodName2(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), activityForButton2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
public void methodName2(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), activityForButton3.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: I have changed v.getContext into view.getContext no errors but it didn't still works whats wrong?

Comment: I have change (v.getContext into view.getContext no errors but it will still not work?